# Where can I find open source 2d bin packing algorithms?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bin-packing

I'm looking for open source (preferably c++) algorithms for 2d bin packing of rectangular and or irregular shapes. I've found several papers on the subject but no code.

Comment: Could this be a variation on this problem? [Calculating a cutting list with the least amount of off cut waste](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145/calculating-a-cutting-list-with-the-least-amount-of-off-cut-waste) I know it isn't the same, but perhaps the algorithms can give you some insight for your own problem.

Comment: This is a dupe of this problem really: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140406/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-how-to-fit-smaller-boxes-into-a-larger-pac

Answer (score -1):

Here is the best to my knowledge about rectangular bin packing:

http://clb.demon.fi/projects/rectangle-bin-packing

Comment: Link only answers are not so useful since the link may become invalid. Please add some more details